# How do install Mysites on port 80 sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, mysite

I have a windows server 2012 serverA  as a front end server and ServerB as app server.

- I have created a Web application on the port 80
- I have created a mysites web application on port 8080

How do I make sure that both web applications on port 80?

In IIS I changed the Binding for Mysites to **http  hostheader mysites  port 80**

is there a step by step guide to  install Mysites on port 80?

I create a mysite collection on the my sites web application

Comment: Don't make these changes in IIS, use the approach Waqas mentions below and create the web app correctly from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Host header for each web application.

- create web app on port 80 using the host headers
- Update the Host Files with entries
- Make sure your AAM is properly setup.

Please check [this blog](http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2012/10/setup-multiple-sharepoint-web.html).

Comment: Not sure what host file changes you make. May want to clarify that.